# C# - Dictionary<String, Action> No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, action

Well, I'm trying to do something in my project. It's network based and I'm using a dictionary to handle my packet prefixes.

> No overload for method 'Add' takes 1 arguments
>   Here's my code anyway:

```
    private Dictionary<string, Action> worldPackets = new Dictionary<string, Action>
    {
        "jr", User.HandleJoinRoom,
        "sm", User.HandleSendMessage,
        "cr", User.HandleCreateRoom
    };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just because you put two values on the same line doesn't make it a key-value entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use curly braces to separate each pair

```
private Dictionary<string, Action> worldPackets = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    { "jr", User.HandleJoinRoom },
    { "sm", User.HandleSendMessage },
    { "cr", User.HandleCreateRoom }
};
```

Comment: Cannot convert from method group to action.

Comment: "User.HandleJoinRoom" is a method group (a function?), not an "Action".

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão A homework for you: compile it and think why it works. `void AMethod() { }
void AnotherMethod() {
    Dictionary<string, Action> worldPackets = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
    {
        {"a",AMethod}
    };
}`

Comment: Well, sorry then, what type of variable would User.HandleJoinRoom be then?

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão then try this: `public class User
{
    public static void AMethod() { Console.WriteLine("aa"); }
}
void AnotherMethod() {
    Dictionary<string, Action> worldPackets = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
    {
        {"a", User.AMethod}
    };
}
`